# Invoke-Expression Unexpected token error when replacing variable in file

Tags: powershell

I want to change version in my deploy.yaml file with powershell. My file (deploy.yaml):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
  labels:
    app: worker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: worker
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        environment: production
        role: apps
      containers:
      - name: worker
        image: https://hub.docker.com/worker:$version
        env:
        - name: ENVIRONMENT
          value: "Production"
        - name: LOGS_DIRECTORY
          value: "/var/log/worker/"
```

When I execute powershell:

```
$version = "1.01"
$workerTemplate = (Get-Content ./deploy.yaml) -join "`n"
$expandedWorkerTemplate = Invoke-Expression "`"$workerTemplate`""
```

I get error:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:22 char:19
+           value: "Production"
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'Production"
        - name: LOGS_DIRECTORY
          value: "/var/log/worker/""' in expression or statement.
At line:4 char:27
+ $expandedWorkerTemplate = Invoke-Expression "`"$workerTemplate`""
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: I recommend not going the `Invoke-Expression` route to allow arbitrary expressions, because you run into obvious trouble trying to stuff things that have to be escaped inside a PowerShell string (like, unsurprisingly, double quotes), aside from potential security implications running code. Instead just replace `$version` as a string. If you *must* do this, I'd recommend using here-strings as they have fewer hangups (``Invoke-Expression ('@' + '"' + "`n" + $workerTemplate + "`n" + '"' + '@')``), but that still leaves room for surprises as YAML is pretty flexible.

Comment: If you just want to replace individual values and aren't planning on stuffing arbitrary runnable code in your template, use something like `$replaceValues = @{ "version" = "1.01" }; foreach ($v in $replaceValues.Keys) { $workerTemplate = $workerTemplate.Replace("$" + $v, $replaceValues[$v]) }`. You can make the syntax for replace values arbitrarily more intricate if dollar signs could reasonably occur in your markup.

Comment: If you are absolutely married to variables for the replacement rather than a hash table, just use those, but still use string-based replace logic: `$t = [System.Text.StringBuilder] $workerTemplate; Get-Variable -Exclude "t" |% { [void] $v.Replace("$" + $_.Name, $_.Value) }; $workerTemplate = [string] $t`. This can replace much more than you expect, though, there's usually more variables in scope than you think. (This is case-sensitive; a case-insensitive approach is more involved since we'll have to dig up `Regex`.)

Comment: If you are not committed to implement your own solution for this, you may want to have a look at existing templating engines for PowerShell, like: https://github.com/baldator/Poshstache

Comment: Not that I recommend this, but you can do `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString((Get-Content .\deploy.yaml -raw))`.

Comment: `ExpandString` looks most reasonable so far. I think you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this would be a good job for PowerShell's [format string operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker
  labels:
    app: worker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: worker
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        environment: production
        role: apps
      containers:
      - name: worker
        image: https://hub.docker.com/worker:{0}
        env:
        - name: ENVIRONMENT
          value: "Production"
        - name: LOGS_DIRECTORY
          value: "/var/log/worker/"
```

You would then expand your template like this:

```
$version = "1.01"
$workerTemplate = Get-Content ./deploy.yaml -Raw
$expandedWorkerTemplate = $workerTemplate -f $version
```

Comment: What if there will be many more parameters and someone accidentally switch positions? I'd like to see variable names in `yaml` file for readability.